# dojotype change the id of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I have a html button using `dojotype` attribute:

```
<button id="btnSearchEmployees" dojotype="dijit.form.Button">
                        Search
                    </button>
```

and trying to use jQuery to handle click event on this button:

```
$("#btnSearchEmployees").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

But it is not working, if I take out `dojotype` attribute, it works normally:

```
 <button id="btnSearchEmployees"> Search </button>
```

How can I avoid this?

**Edit:** Here is what dojo change:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" role="presentation" style="width: 70px;" widgetid="btnSearchEmployee">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" role="presentation">
        <span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="btnSearchEmployee_label" tabindex="0" id="btnSearchEmployee">
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="btnSearchEmployee_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Search</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span>
```

Comment: What's the error you receive? I'm curious. What's your !DOCTYPE set to, as well?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: nothing happens, seem dojotype change the id of button

Comment: What does the ID get changed to?

Comment: Why don't you stay at one framework using `registry.byId('btnSearchEmployees').connect('onClick', function(){ alert('test'); })` instead?

Comment: @nozzleman: just technical decision, we are trying to use jQuery instead of dojo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("btnSearchEmployees"), "onClick", function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

It is because once you use dojoType(or data-dojo-type). The [dojo parser](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html) will replace the original dom into the template which your dijit declares. The result may be completely different with what your markup writes(as showed by you). It generate a new id for the outermost dom. So what you actually click is not the original Button element. Then you have to use it as "dojo widget", which can only retrieved via **dijit.byId**.

If you are using dojo framework already, it has most features you need. You don't have to use JQuery as well.